# Can one use XmlAttributes to selectively XmlIgnore?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a rather large class to serialize as Xml, and in order to reduce the wasted space would like to selectively XmlIgnore some of the class properties.  For example, one property in the class is assigned a value only one out of ten times or so, and if I code the serialization attribute as follows

```
[XmlAttribute]
public String WorkClass
{
    get { return _workClass; }
    set { _workClass = value; }
}
```

If there is no value (most of the time) this is serialized over and over again as

```
WorkClass=""
```

Is there an option or attribute that would ignore the property for serialization if its value is empty, but not ignore it if it is not empty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create methods for each of the values you wish to not have serialized

The following method will return `true` when `WorkClass` contains something other than an empty string, if you're using .NET Framework 4, you could elect to use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` which would also check for blank spaces `' '`.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeWorkClass() {
  return !string.IsNullOrEmtpy(WorkClass);
}
```

When the Xml Serializer runs, it will look for this method, based on the naming convention and then choose whether to serialize that property or not.

The name of the method should always begin with `ShouldSerialize` and then end with the property name. Then you simply need to return a boolean based on whatever conditional you want, as to whether to serialize the value or not.

Comment: That's amazing!  It's also non-intuitive IMHO.  I would have expected some kind of modifier on the serialization attribute, you know, something like [XmlAttribute(IgnoreOnNullOrEmpty="true")].